# Non uniform interpolation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, interpolation

I have been reading a bout Super Resolution image reconstruction topic, the aim of this field is to create a high resolution(HR) image from multiple shifted (sub-pixel) low resolution(LR) images. the following code creates 4 LR images from one HR image. then uses non-unifrom interpolation to interpolate the 4 LR images on High resolution grid to get back the HR image which is larger than the LR ones by 4 in both sides.

**main.m**

```
im=double(imread('lena.bmp'));

figure,imshow(uint8(im)),title('original HR image');
shifts=[ 0,         0;
        4.1,    2.68;
       -3.7,    7.8;
       -1.1,  -6.5];

factor=4;

im1=create_low(im,shifts(1,1),shifts(1,2),factor);
im2=create_low(im,shifts(2,1),shifts(2,2),factor);
im3=create_low(im,shifts(3,1),shifts(3,2),factor);
im4=create_low(im,shifts(4,1),shifts(4,2),factor);

LR_images={im1,im2,im3,im4};

estimated_image =  interpolate(LR_images,shifts,factor);
figure,imshow(uint8(estimated_image)),title('reconstructed image');
```

**create_low.m**  This function creates the 4 LR images.

```
function [ low ] = create_low(im,x_shift,y_shift,factor)

 low = shift(im,x_shift,y_shift);

 low=downsample(low,factor);
 low=low';
 low = downsample(low,factor);
 low=low';

end
```

[shift.m](http://paste.ofcode.org/38cQAU4t5qL9hnTkYPtVsGu) This function makes sub-pixel shift by linear interpolation.

**interpolate.m** Interpolates the 4 LR images onto HR grid.

```
function rec = interpolate(s,shifts,factor)                                   

n=length(s);
ss = size(s{1});
if (length(ss)==2) ss=[ss 1]; end

% compute the coordinates of the pixels from the N images.
for k=1:ss(3) % for each color channel
  for i=1:n % for each image
    s_c{i}=s{i}(:,:,k);
    s_c{i} = s_c{i}(:);     
    r{i} = [1:factor:factor*ss(1)]'*ones(1,ss(2)); % create matrix with row indices
    c{i} = ones(ss(1),1)*[1:factor:factor*ss(2)]; % create matrix with column indices
    r{i} = r{i}+factor*shifts(i,2);     %% the problem is here.
    c{i} = c{i}+factor*shifts(i,1);     %% the problem is here.
    rn{i} = r{i}((r{i}>0)&(r{i}<=factor*ss(1))&(c{i}>0)&(c{i}<=factor*ss(2)));
    cn{i} = c{i}((r{i}>0)&(r{i}<=factor*ss(1))&(c{i}>0)&(c{i}<=factor*ss(2)));
    sn{i} = s_c{i}((r{i}>0)&(r{i}<=factor*ss(1))&(c{i}>0)&(c{i}<=factor*ss(2)));
 end

 s_ = []; r_ = []; c_ = []; sr_ = []; rr_ = []; cr_ = [];
 for i=1:n % for each image
    s_ = [s_; sn{i}];
    r_ = [r_; rn{i}];
    c_ = [c_; cn{i}];
 end
 clear s_c r c coord rn cn sn

 % interpolate the high resolution pixels using cubic interpolation
 rec_col = griddata(c_,r_,s_,[1:ss(2)*factor],[1:ss(1)*factor]','cubic'); 
 rec(:,:,k) = reshape(rec_col,ss(1)*factor,ss(2)*factor);
end
rec(isnan(rec))=0;
```

I used `griddata` function for interpolation(cubic) and the reconstructed image is too bad because i think that the values of the arguments of 'griddata` are wrong. How to correct them?

Note: when i change this code

```
r{i} = r{i}+factor*shifts(i,2);     %% the problem is here.
c{i} = c{i}+factor*shifts(i,1);     %% the problem is here.
```

to

```
r{i} = r{i}-shifts(i,2);     %% the problem is here.
c{i} = c{i}-shifts(i,1);     %% the problem is here.
```

I get a good image, but i don't know why!

**Edit**
`lena.bmp`

[image]

Comment: Can you post the `lena.bmp` you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In create_low you apply shifts in high resolution coordinates. So in interpolate you also shall apply the shifts in high resolution coordinates. As such it totally makes sense that you should NOT multiply them by factor -- as you already found out.